# MVC Parse XML from Web Service

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to parse the xml results from a web service but I am getting an error `{The best overloaded method match for 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments"}`

```
var service = new RemoteService.RemoteSoapClient("RemoteSoap");
var result = service.GetDetails(systemId, appId);

ViewBag.Surname = XElement.Parse(result).Descendants("Customer").Single().Attribute("Surname").Value;
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<List>
-<Customer>
<Surname>Spack</Surname>
<Firstname>Bob</Firstname>
</Customer>
</List>
```

What am I doing wrong, please help.

Comment: What is the data type `GetDetails()` method return?

Comment: What's the type of result?  What's the full exception details?  Also, is that really your xml?  Because as it appears in your question it's not xml .

Comment: My Web Service uses `[WebMethod] public XmlDocument GetDetails(string systemId, string appId)` so I should be returning an XML Document.

Answer (score 0):

If you F12 XElement.Parse you can see it only has two separate method signatures, in both of which the expected first parameter is a string.  I'm going to guess service.GetDetails does not return a string.

If you throw a .ToString() at the end of your ViewBag.Surname assignment that should at least get you out of your compile error.  Whether or not that actually gets you the data you expect, hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggested, `XElement.Parse()` expect `string` as argument (instead of `XmlDocument` as you currently passed).

You can use [`XmlDocument.OuterXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.outerxml.aspx) to get string markup representation of `XmlDocument` :

```
ViewBag.Surname = XElement.Parse(result.OuterXml)
                          .Descendants("Customer")
                          .Single()
                          .Element("Surname")
                          .Value;
```

Comment: Thank you, that sorted that error, now I have a new one `'object' does not contain a definition for 'Single'` all I want is the Surname returning, could you please see my XML output and identify where I an mow going wrong?

Comment: I didn't get such error here. But one thing I noticed, Surname is a node/element not attribute.

Comment: I've modified the code as per your suggestion and I am now getting the error `'object' does not contain a definition for 'Single'` any ideas?

Comment: strange, no idea. `XElement.Descendants()` should never return `object`, [it returns `IEnumerable<XElement>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)